# How can I prevent a specific field from submitting a form with jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms

Given the following very simplistic fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ofy3bhuf/

I want to prevent the form from being submitted if enter is pressed on the #no_return input, but it should be submitted as normal if return is pressed on any other input.

As you see in the fiddle, I have actions on the form submit event and the keyup event for #no_return. The submit event always occurs first, but even if it didn't, would I able able to prevent the submit event from the input keyup event?

Code:

```
<form action='scratch_clean' method='get'>
  <input id='return' />
  <input id="no_return" />
  <input type='submit' />
</form>
<div id='result'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#no_return').on('keyup', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var code = e.which;
      if(code==13)
      {
        $('#result').append('keyup<br>');
        return false;
      }
      //return false; // not needed

  });
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#result').append('submit<br>');
    // EDIT: Other processing happens here
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#result').append('submit<br>');
    return false;
  });
});

$('#no_return').on('keypress', function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
  }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ofy3bhuf/1/)

Comment: Almost, but it was getting hit twice, so I removed keyup and it's good. Thanks!